# How to run .NET 2.0 assembly in a .NET 4.0 applicaton

Tags: .net

I have a .NET 4.0 web application that uses a .NET 2.0 assembly.  I've added the reference to the 2.0 assembly and added this

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
</startup>
```

in the web.config file. Problem is I still get a compile time error stating that I'm "missing an assembly reference".  I've even decompiled the assembly and recompiled it in .NET 4.0, and
still no luck.

Please assist?

Comment: If you've tried this with .NET 2 and 4 then the title of the question isn't _really_ the question. The problem obviously runs deeper, or, at least, differently.

Comment: I believe the config file has nothing to do with compilation, it is only read at run time. I think you have a different problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you include all the dependencies of the .NET 2 DLL? For example, if I'm using the System.Xaml.dll and create an instance of the XamlXmlReader class but I've actually haven't included the System.Xml.dll in my project, I get the same error. Also I'm pretty sure that this message would give you some kind of a hint, which part of your application caused it.

Comment: Thx mate, the assembly had references toe System.Web.MVC, System.Web.Abstraction, and System.Web.Routing which I failed to add.

Answer (score 2):

Framework 4.0 does not includes (as 3.5 previously did) the 2.0 framework.

First of all you must install also the 2.0 framework on your PC.

Comment: Thx Matteo, .NET 2.0 is installed though

Comment: I believe that would cause a runtime exception, not a compile-time error.